# XML + Indesign - copy tagged elements with hierachy

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign

I'm using Indesign to create a catalog with multiple page templates and import the data from a xml export from the website.

In order to use 7 different templates I created lots of tagged frames.
The import works well. (thanks to [Indesign and XML - how to auto flow into multiple pages with differing styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427681/indesign-and-xml-how-to-auto-flow-into-multiple-pages-with-differing-styles))

But I need to copy the elements and the structure to around 200 pages. 
My Problem is that the structure changes when copying the elements to a new page and also when I duplicate the page. 
I think the tags are sorted alphabetically when copying but I can't find settings or something else to change that.

Is there a way to avoid this problem or is there no other way then to sort 50 tags on 200 pages? PLEASE Help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug entry that also resolves this issue. 
If you copy the elements, then undo the copying with CRTL + Z and then redo it with CTRL + Shift + Z the structure is kept in the right order:

https://forums.adobe.com/message/3445337#3445337